# Modifying features in-place with a model

Tags: qgis, vector, editing, qgis-modeler

QGIS has some processing algorithms that allow [modifying the layer's features in-place](https://docs.qgis.org/3.24/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#the-processing-in-place-layer-modifier).

How can I create a tool in the graphical modeler that allows for the same **in-place editing** functionality, e. g. a simple buffer for each feature of its input without creating a new layer?

Comment: Are you asking how to use the [modeler](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/processing/modeler_twi.html?highlight=model)?

Comment: How to build a model with it that allows in-place editing